# Can you find a better argument for this result in a thermodynamics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, equilibrium

Imagine two systems, A and B, both containing the same ideal gas and connected through a small tube such that they can interchange particles. They start out at $p_i$ and $T_i=T_A$, which for system A is kept constant through a thermostatic bath. The question is, what's the maximum increase in pressure you can achieve under mechanical equilibrium conditions by heating up B? The answer sheet states that $p_f=2p_i$. My argument for this goes as follows:

Take system A, here we have:

$$p_i=\frac{n_{A,i}RT_A}{V_A}=Kn_{A,i}$$

$$p_f=\frac{n_{A,f}RT_A}{V_A}=Kn_{A,f}$$

Therefore:

$$p_f/p_i=n_{A,f}/n_{A,i}=x$$

If we assume that $n_{A,i}=n_{B,i}$, the maximum value for $x$ is simply $x=2$, as then $n_{A,f}=2n_{A,i}=n_{A,i}+n_{B,i}=n_T$ (the total amount of gas). With this, $p_f=2p_i$.

While the argument gives the correct result, it just seems very unintuitive to me. **Independent of this specific example, what broad insight can be applied to clarify gas behavior in the limit of infinite temperature on either side of a small hole between chambers?** For example, why would all the gas go to container A, instead of going to container B where temperature is higher? So can someone find a better way to explain the result? Thanks.

Comment: At infinite temperature in container B the gas molecules go infinitely fast (assuming these are non-relativistic gases, otherwise we are in trouble). They are therefor always going to return to container A in zero time, where they get thermalized to the temperature in A. They can therefor only return at a finite speed to B. Finite diffusion one way, infinite diffusion the other can only be achieved with all the gas in A. Having said that, the heat flow from B to A would also be infinite...

Comment: Even if all the gas in B went into container A, if the temperature in A were kept constant, the pressure in A could never get higher than $2p_i$.  At final equilibrium, the pressure in B would have to match A.  So $p_{bf}=2p_i=\frac{n_{Bf}RT_{Bf}}{V_B}$, and $n_{Bf}T_{Bf}=2p_iV_B/R$.  The right hand side is a constant, so if the final temperature of B became very high, the number of moles of gas in B would have to approach zero.

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close, as the comments by @FlatterMann and Chet contain useful insights and concepts  applicable to a broad range of gas problems. They would make appropriate answers.